# For a Borel subset $B$ of a complete, seperable metric space $S$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there exists compact $C \subset S$ with $P(B) < P(C) + \epsilon$.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces, borel-sets, borel-measures

For my bachelor thesis, I've been studying iterated random functions and a very limited amount of measure theory to understand it rigorously. One thing I could not understand is the following:

Suppose $S$ is a complete, seperable metric space and equip this with its Borel sigma-algebra. Let $P$ be a probability measure on this measurable space. Now given a Borel subset $B \subset S$ and $\epsilon > 0$, then there exists a compact subset $C \subset B$ such that $P(B) < P(C) + \epsilon$.

I don't understand why such $C$ must exist. To be honest, I haven't got a clue how to even look for such $C$, or why $B$ would even contain a non-trivial compact subset. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Hi Steve. Have you included all the hypotheses about $S$? Talking about both $P$ and $Q$ here seems like a red herring - it suffices to prove the existence of such a $C$ for just $P$. This is called "inner regularity" or "tightness", which is automatically true for eg complete separable metric spaces, discussed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/22177). The proof likely becomes progressively easier the more you already know about $S$, $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to mention that $S$ is complete and seperable, my apologies. I also understand that talking about 2 probability measures is unnecessary. I edited the questions according to this. Thank you for referencing the book, it helped mr a great deal! Although tightness as described in the book you mentioned was not enough for this statement, I did manage to find an easy proof that tightness and regularity implies it.